# How insert new row with the percentage

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
select t.cod_provincia as prov, COUNT(t.cod_provincia) as conto
from clienti t 
where t.data_ins between to_date(&da_data,'ddmmrr') and to_date(&a_data,'ddmmrr')
and t.cod_iso='ITA'
group by t.cod_provincia
```

it returns

[image]

Now I want a new col to view the CONTO value in percent for each row. haw can I do it?
For each row I want the value `[CONTO*100]/SUM(CONTO)`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, but you can explain me the logic solution in SQL standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select pov, conto*100/sum(conto) over()
  from (
       select t.cod_provincia as prov, COUNT(t.cod_provincia) as conto
         from clienti t 
        where t.data_ins between to_date(&da_data,'ddmmrr') and to_date(&a_data,'ddmmrr')
          and t.cod_iso='ITA'
        group by t.cod_provincia
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a built-in analytic function RATIO_TO_REPORT that can be used as an alternative to Rusty's solution:

```
select t.cod_provincia as prov,
       count(t.cod_provincia) as conto,
       100*RATIO_TO_REPORT(count(t.cod_provincia)) OVER () as percentage 
from clienti t 
where t.data_ins between to_date(&da_data,'ddmmrr') and to_date(&a_data,'ddmmrr')
and t.cod_iso='ITA'
group by t.cod_provincia
```

It gives the same result but avoids repeating an expression both as numerator and within the sum in the denominator. And you do not need to worry about potential division by zero errors.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT t.cod_provincia        AS prov,
       Count(t.cod_provincia) AS conto,
       ( Count(t.cod_provincia) * 100 ) / Sum(cod_provincia)
FROM   clienti t
WHERE  t.data_ins between to_date(&da_data,'ddmmrr') and to_date(&a_data,'ddmmrr')
and    t.cod_iso = 'ITA'
GROUP  BY t.cod_provincia
```

Comment: not work. I try `( Count(t.cod_provincia) * 100 ) / Sum(t.cod_provincia)` but I have an error